# Custom template tags with PHP and MySQL

Tags: php

Let's say i'm creating a blog platform where users can edit their template with HTML tags, would it be possible doing something like the following code?

```
<links>
 <a href="<%LinkUrl%>"><%Link%></a>
 <a href="<%LinkUrl%>"><%Link%></a>
</links>
```

To manage that, how should I proceed? Is there a easy way to do this?
I have looked at Smarty template engine, but that is way too difficult for a user without much experience of programming. Other solutions avaliable for this purpose?

It would be interesting if someone could give me a briefing on how I could create something similiar. Not looking for finished code in any way - just some help getting started.

Comment: Smarty is too difficult? `<a href="{$LinkUrl}">{$Link}</a>`

Comment: *"Is there a easy way to do this?"* Yes, use an existing template parser. I prefer Twig: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/

Comment: You should evaluate pre-existing template systems before writing your own. These are easy to prototype, but much harder to implement correctly.

Comment: WOW what is wrong with `<?=$LinkUrl?>` ? No bloat, no parsing, it just works.

Comment: @AbraCadaver Letting users run any PHP code they want is extremely dangerous, and there's no way really to sandbox functionality (like limit it to echo/print). Some butthole can write `unlink('index.php');` or much worse and it will be your fault.

Comment: That's ridiculous if they are in possession of the files!  MS fault if I type `format c:` or Ubuntu's fault if I type `rm -rf *`?

Comment: @AbraCadaver Yes, it's called a security vulnerability in your software. I *think* you missed the point. Re-read the question for context. "a blog platform where users can edit their template with HTML tags". It's an extremely common requirement.

Comment: @Wesley Murch:  If "blog platform" refers to an online blog (like worpress.com) that users sign up for and edit templates online, then yes I agree. I took it as an app that users would host and create their own templates.

Answer (score 1):

Try to work yourself into regular expressions. You can achieve what you want with them.

[Tutorial](http://weblogtoolscollection.com/regex/regex.php)

[preg_replace() manual](http://php.net/manual/de/function.preg-replace.php)